# orgmode: File not fully loaded into buffer

Tags: org-mode

When I try to open an *.org file that I have previously created and saved, Emacs only displays the first line of the file in the buffer. I load the file with <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd>. I witnessed this behavior for org files only. When I open the org file with another editor (sublime, notepad, etc...) the whole data is there so the file itself seems fine.
Could not find any documentation on this behavior.

Comment: Exporting to html works, I should add, even though I don't see the whole content in emacs itself.

Comment: Apologies if this is obvious - not sure how new you might be to Org mode -
but by default an org file is opened with the outline tree collapsed (see `org-startup-folded`). Can you just hit tab on that first line to expand the tree?

Comment: @glucas You don't have to apologize, because exactly that was the case. I am completely new to org-mode (and emacs).

Comment: Ah - glad to help then! I'll turn my comment in to an answer so you can resolve this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior: by default, org files are opened in a folded overview state. You can use <kbd>TAB</kbd> (bound to `org-cycle`) to expand the outline tree.

If you prefer your Org files to open in an already-expanded state, you can either customize the startup behavior:

```
M-x customize-option org-startup-folded
```

Or you can control this per Org file by adding something like:

```
#+STARTUP: nofold
```

(See [Visibility Cycling](http://orgmode.org/manual/Visibility-cycling.html#Visibility-cycling) in the Org manual for more.)